PowerShell loading .NET dependencies from current working directory instead of PowerShell modules directory
I have an application allows the execution of PowerShell code.  I'm attempting to run Microsoft Graph cmdlets. I have the Microsoft Graph PS Modules installed. When I run Get-Module -ListAvailable, I see version 2.8.0. The cmdlets that I'm using are:

Connect-MgGraph
Update-MgUser

Update-MgUser comes from the Microsoft.Graph.User PowerShell module. The Microsoft.Graph.User module has a dependency on Microsoft.Graph.Authentication. If I look in

C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\microsoft.graph.Authentication\2.8.0\Dependencies

, I see Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll version 3.0.9.0. The problem is when the application runs my PS code and PowerShell or .NET loads it's dependencies, it is loading Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll from the application directory (version 2.0.9.0) which has a different signature for one of the classes. This 2.0.9.0 version of Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll is required by other components of the application, therefore I cannot remove or upgrade it.
What's odd is that if I run those cmdlets from the PowerShell command line with my working directory as the application directory with the v2.0.9.0 version of Microsoft.Graph.Core.dll, I don't get an error. I'm not sure how this application is creating the Powershell environment.
My question is how is PowerShell and ultimately .NET loading the dependencies and any idea why it would be preferring the DLLs in the application directory as opposed to the dependency directory for the PowerShell module?
